# ML - Text input data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, predictive-models, scikit-learn

I'm trying to explore an use-case in ML but stuck at a point. May i please request your advise please.

Have a service desk web application for logging tickets, which is essentially a form having various fields like -

```
subject,
content, 
username, 
emailid,
category - {hardware, application, datafix, mobileapp, etc.}, 
service group - {AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, etc.}, 
domain - {email, walkin, phonecall, etc.},
priority - {high, medium, low}
```

(Apologies for the poor quality of sample data provided above.)

Based on this info, the ticket is then manually assigned to respective team owners for resolution.

My intent is to use ML - based on the above fields, predict the Team who will work on this ticket. (Team ex. HR or IT or Desktop support or Pantry or Facilities, etc. )

1) Can this use-case be categorised as Multi-class classification problem?
2) The field values are stored as words in database. How can it be fed to my ML as numbers?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance,
RB
(on Python 3.6)

Comment: Is the variable `service group` the eventual assignment that you want to predict?

Comment: Have you had a look at the natural language processing (NLP) literature or e.g. the fast.ai course?

Comment: @Carl - Not 'service group'. I want to predict the 'Team' where the ticket has to be assigned. I have historical data where based on the above features, service desk team had assigned (manually) the tickets to various teams.

Comment: @Bjorn - Not yet. I had been focusing more into regression and classification mechanisms. But, why do you suggest NLP ? Please advise.

Comment: It is unclear to me at least what `service group` is. It is unclear to me how many teams there are and what they do. It is unclear how these variables are distributed. It is unclear what causes an assignment to which team, and whether or not the assignments are currently being performed correctly. It is unclear what type of statistical model (linear, nonlinear, type) can be used to predict assignments.

Comment: @Carl - You can think of `service group` as specific application areas or division within a category. Ex. For category 'Application', we can have multiple `service group` like - Microsoft applications, or Oracle database, or AWS, or GitHub, or etc.

Comment: Suggest that you are using a decision tree of the if...then type currently. Either one figures out what decision tree is being used or one uses a neural net to attempt to duplicate it, without thinking it through. Personally, I would use the former method as it is more nuts and bolts and can be altered without having to train a network all over again.